# Finding the angle between vectors $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ in radians

Tags: vectors

Two unit vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ in $\Bbb R^n$ satisfy $\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ in radians. How would I go about finding the angle between $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$?

As I don't know the $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ unit vectors, would the unit circle be useful here? For instance, using $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and plugging those values into $\dfrac{\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y}}{\mathbf{\|x\| \|y\|}}$ to find the angle?

Comment: Have in mind that $x \cdot y$ is not in radians (or in anything), it is just a number so it has no particular unit of measure.

Comment: “As I don’t know the $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ unit vectors…” — You said in the first statement that they’re unit vectors.

Comment: “satisfy $\mathbf x\cdot\mathbf y=\frac{\sqrt2}2$ in radians” — The unit of the angle does not affect what the dot product is, nor does it affect the actual measure of the angle. Whether I say I’m 6 ft or 183 cm doesn’t affect my BMI nor does it affect my actual height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I believe the unit circle is not really involved here.

It is simple. You already know the $cosinus$ of the angle $\theta$ between the two vectors. It is this expression:

$$cos(\theta) = \dfrac{\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y}}{\mathbf{||x||\cdot ||y||}}$$

Just plug in the numbers in this formula. Thus you get:

$$cos(\theta) = \frac{\sqrt{2}/2}{1.1}$$

And once you know that $a = cos(\theta) = \sqrt{2}/2$,
find $\theta = \arccos(a) = \arccos(\sqrt{2}/2) = \pi / 4$

Comment: Superb explanation, peter. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The dotproduct between two vectors in euclidean space can be defined as
$$\textbf{x}\cdot\textbf{y} = \cos\theta||\textbf{x}||||\textbf{y}||$$
Since you have unit vectors: $||\textbf{x}||,||\textbf{y}||=1$. The angle $\theta$ is then given by
$$\theta = \arccos(\textbf{x}\cdot\textbf{y})=\arccos(\sqrt{2}/2)=\pi/4$$